# Laravel Request has wildcards for complex url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Lets say I have a url like so

`http://www.mywebsitetest.com/users/1023/edit/photo/12`

I want to be able to use the `Request` with wildcards for the whole URL, but it doesn't seem to be working.

For example, I want to add a disabled attribute to a select box based on if the user is currently being edited not created, and i'm doing it like this

```
<select
  @if(Request::has('*users/*/edit'))
    readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled"
  @endif
>
</select>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I structure the `Request::has()` with wildcards when its a long complicated url?

Answer (score 4):

Silly mistake on my part! For anyone else trying to achieve this, you need to use `Request::is()` not `Request::has()`.

So for the url

`http://www.mywebsitetest.com/users/1023/edit/photo/12`

To check if it has `edit` a simple

```
@if(Request::is('*edit*'))
    readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled"
@endif
```

Or

```
@if(Request::is('*/users/*/edit'))
    readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled"
@endif
```

Will work fine. Quick simple mistake by me, just thought id answer it incase anyone else has the same confusion/issue!